# Hierarchical semantic distances dataset

Tags: data-request, nlp, language, wordnet

I need data (preferably human judgment) for the structural/hierarchical semantic distance between many couples (at least hundreds) of words.

For example, d(computer, television) < d(radio, television) < d(dish washer, television).

If we organize all words in a dendrogram or a tree, where each node is a category ("electric device", "with screen", etc...), and words are in leaves, the number will represent several steps (nodes) we have to go from one word to another.

Does such a dataset exist? per couples ratings are enough, no need to have a full embeding/tree/specify the nodes (An example dataset will be:

Computer Television 1

Radio Television 2

DishWasher Television 3

I'm aware of the WordNet database but it has some very unintuitive definitions and the results achieved using it are not very correspond to human ratings. I would like to have a more human-rating alike data-set.

Comment: One keyword that might be helpful is "semantic differential" by Osgood.

Comment: You could create such a list from wikidata.org but it'd probably be ever worse than WordNet.